# Showing that $||x||^k$ is $C^{k-1}$ but not $C^k$ when $k$ is odd

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ be given by $f(x) = ||x||^k$ where $k$ is odd. I'm trying to show that $f$ is $C^{k-1}$ but not $C^k$. The problematic point is $0$.

I can show that if $k>1$ then at least $f$ is at least $C^1$ at $0$. Indeed, consider the directional derivative:
$$  \partial_v f(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0+tv) - f(0)}{|t|} = \lim_{t \to 0} |t|^{k-1} ||v||^k = 0 $$
Since this limit exists and the assignment $v \mapsto \partial_vf(0)$ is linear, I think this shows that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. But I'm not sure how to upgrade this to $C^{k-1}$. Since $f$ is homogeneous of degree $k$, I feel that somehow this might be useful here. A concrete idea I had was to consider a "higher order directional derivative". I can imagine that somehow at $k-1$ the calculation above would still yield $0$, but once we reach $k$th order it would fail to be linear, hence not $C^k$. But I'm not sure how to write what I said above rigorously.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am assuming that $||x||$ denotes the Euclidian 2-norm.
In that case, when $k = 2p + 1$, we can write
$$
||x||^{k} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 right)^{p} \sqrt{ \sum{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 }  
$$
The first term is polynomial in the coordinates and it can be shown to be $C^{k-1}$ with the $(k-1)$-th derivative being the first derivative non-zero at 0. Using the Leibniz rule (derivate of a product of functions), you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Why does this mean it's not $C^k$?

Comment: Consider first $n = 1$. Then the question is: what is the regularity of $f(x) = x^{k-1} | x |$ ?

Comment: Ok, I can see how using the the Leibniz rule, we get $f^{(k-1)} = c_1 |x| + c_2 x |x|^{(1)} + \cdots + c_{k} x |x|^{(k-1)}$ and $f^{(k)} = 0 |x| + a_2 |x|^{(1)} + \cdots $ where the $c_i$ and $a_i$ are constants. I'm not sure how to apply this to show that $f$ is $C^{k-1}$ but not $C^k$. I see that evaluated at $x=0$, $f^{(k-1)}(x)$ will vanish whereas for $f^{(k)}(x)$ the term $a_2 |x|^{(1)}$ seems to be the problem? But I'm not sure how to translate this into a statement about differentiability. If we were talking about $C^1$ then I'd just use the limit definition to show that the limits...

Comment: ...from both sides are different, but I'm not sure what to do in this higher order case? Note that above I'm assuming that $k = 2p+1$ is odd, so we can split up $|x|^{k} = x^{k-1}|x|$ as you wrote.